# As part of maven build how to read all the resource files from dependencies in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

As part of maven build how to read all the resource files from dependencies in pom.xml.
Problem Statement :
I have three dependencies in my pom.xml file and each dependency is having list of xml files in resource folder, Now I want to read all the xmls from all the dependencies as part of maven build using java and create a sing file and save in given path.

````
Example : pom.xml file.
```<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>merge</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.test</groupId>
     <artifactId>first</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.test</groupId>
     <artifactId>second</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.test</groupId>
     <artifactId>three</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>```

Resource file in dependencies : 
In "first" dependency resources.
 /src/main/resources/test/first-1.xml
 /src/main/resources/test/first-2.xml
 /src/main/resources/test/first-3.xml

In "second" dependency resources.
  /src/main/resources/test/second-1.xml
  /src/main/resources/test/second-2.xml

In "three" dependency resources.
   /src/main/resources/test/three-1.xml
   /src/main/resources/test/three-2.xml

 Expected Output:
 It should combine all above xml files and create merge-all.xml file in "merge" jar.
````

There is a one root.xml file and then copy content of the other xml files and generate a new xml file name.
For Example :

1. root.xml : first jar

````
<cache-config
 xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config/1.2/coherence-cache-config.xsd">
 <caching-scheme-mapping>
     <cache-mapping>
         <cache-name>local-cache</cache-name>
         <scheme-name>local-scheme</scheme-name>
     </cache-mapping>
 </caching-scheme-mapping>
 <caching-schemes>
     <local-scheme>
         <scheme-name>local-scheme</scheme-name>
         <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
         <high-units>10</high-units>
         <expiry-delay>5s</expiry-delay>
     </local-scheme>
 </caching-schemes>
</cache-config> ```

2) one.xml : second jar

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cache-config
xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config/1.2/coherence-cache-config.xsd">
<caching-scheme-mapping>
<cache-mapping>
  <cache-name>one-cache</cache-name>
  <scheme-name>local-scheme</scheme-name>
</cache-mapping>
</caching-scheme-mapping>
<caching-schemes>

</caching-schemes>
</cache-config>

out.xml : the final generated out put.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cache-config
xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config/1.2/coherence-cache-config.xsd">
<caching-scheme-mapping>
<cache-mapping>
  <cache-name>local-cache</cache-name>
  <scheme-name>local-scheme</scheme-name>
</cache-mapping>
<cache-mapping>
  <cache-name>one-cache</cache-name>
  <scheme-name>local-scheme</scheme-name>
</cache-mapping>
</caching-scheme-mapping>
<caching-schemes>
<local-scheme>
  <scheme-name>local-scheme</scheme-name>
  <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
  <high-units>10</high-units>
  <expiry-delay>5s</expiry-delay>
</local-scheme>
</caching-schemes>
</cache-config>```
````

Comment: I guess you need to write a Maven plugin for that.

Comment: Presumably you need to parse the XML files, not just concatenate them?

Comment: If you use the assembly plugin you can create a containerDescriptorHandler to process the files in dependencies, and add new files.

Comment: could you please help me with the maven plugin APIs for reading all resource from dependencies.

Comment: You'll need an assembly descriptor which puts those XML files into your final artefact (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) and then write a containerDescriptorHandler to merge the xml files (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/using-container-descriptor-handlers.html) You didn't answer my question above regarding what you actually need to do to the XML files.

Comment: I have added a example for xml merge.

Comment: If you want to use the approach I'm suggesting, I think you should try to do it, and ask a new question if you get stuck. Looking at how you need to merge the XML files you will need to write your own containerDescriptorHandler, rather than being able to use one of the defaults.